# Memory and Assembly Language/ Operating Systems

Tags: assembly, system

The following question is on my test review for Operating Systems but I don't know how to answer it. I would give a first attempt at them problem but I really don't know how to start it either.

```
Given the following information for an assembly language program:

Process code size = 3126 bytes, Page size = 1042 bytes

Instruction at memory location 532:  Load 1, 2098

Instruction at memory location 1156:  Add 1, 4087

Instruction at memory location 2086:  Sub 1, 1052

Data at memory location 1052:  015672

Data at memory location 2098:  114321

Data at memory location 4087:  077435

(a) How many pages are needed to store the entire process code?
Show calculations.

(b) Compute the page number and displacement for each of the byte
e byte
addresses where the data is stored (recall that page numbering
starts at 0).

(c) Are page numbers and displacements legal for this process?
Explain.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A** - Given `Process code size = 3126 bytes, Page size = 1042 bytes` then
No. of pages = `process code size` / `page size`
No. of pages = `3`

**B** - 1052 = Page 1 (or the second page), displacement = 10 `1052 = 1042 + 10`
2098 = Page 2 (or the third page), displacement = 14 `2098 = (1042 * 2) + 14`
4087 = Page 3 (or the fourth page), displacement = 961 `4087 = (1042 * 3) + 961`

**C** - Unlikely. 4087 appears to be well past the process size (e.g. by 961 bytes). But, it depends on your platform.